Trying to get dict[k] from a dict in a list of dicts for k in list or string
I have a couple dictionaries with differing values for the same keys.
I have a list of these dicts and I want to return the values from only 1 of the dicts based on the matched keys inside a different list or string.
I want it to reflect the dict with a matching list index as the first str in the other list.
group1 = {'1': [0, 0], '2': [2, 2], '3': [3, 3], '4': [4, 4], '5': [5, 5]}
group2 = {'1': [2, 2], '2': [0, 0], '3': [4, 4], '4': [5, 5], '5': [6, 6]}
group3 = {'1': [3, 3], '2': [4, 4], '3': [0, 0], '4': [6, 6], '5': [7, 7]}

group_selection = [group1, group2, group3]

example = ['2', '5', '3', '3', '1', '2']

groups_assigned = [group_selection[k] for k in example]
print(groups_assigned)
# Desired goal is [[0, 0], [6, 6], [4, 4], [4, 4], [2, 2], [0, 0]]   

So far the only way that has worked is
result = [groups_assigned[1][k] for k in example]

I want to be select through the list of dicts to get the correct dict.
For the first value in list being '2' it should return the group2 dict values for all remaining string values in list from rest of keys in that dict.
'1' would relate to group1, '2' would relate to group2 for as reference
['1', '2', '4', '5'] = [[0, 0], [2, 2], [4, 4], [5, 5]]
and
['3', '1'] = [[0,0], [3, 3]]

this should do
result = [group_selection[int(example[0])-1][x] for x in example]


I am unsure if I have understand the requirements.
I think this should do the trick:
result = [groups_assigned[int(example[0], 10)][k] for k in example]

So instead of hard coding the index to 1 you can read the wanted index from the first element of the iterable (string or list in your case) and convert it to int. This way you have the a zero based index access.
If you change it to
result = [groups_assigned[int(example[0], 10) - 1][k] for k in example]

You should have what you want. For a list starting with ['1', ...] you have the dict with index 0 for ['2', ...] you have the index 1 and so on.
Of course this way fails if you have only a list with three dicts and you have example lists like ['5', ...], or ['-1', ...]
But this could be easly done
group1 = {"1": [0, 0], "2": [2, 2], "3": [3, 3], "4": [4, 4], "5": [5, 5]}
group2 = {"1": [2, 2], "2": [0, 0], "3": [4, 4], "4": [5, 5], "5": [6, 6]}
group3 = {"1": [3, 3], "2": [4, 4], "3": [0, 0], "4": [6, 6], "5": [7, 7]}

group_selection = [group1, group2, group3]

def assigned_groups(example: list[str]) -> list[list[int]]:
    global group_selection

    # -1 to convert 1 based index to 0 based index
    index = int(example[0], 10) - 1
    if not (0 <= index < len(group_selection)):
        raise ValueError("first element of example is invalid")

    return [group_selection[index][k] for k in example]


#declare variables group1, group2, group3 and their values as key, value pair of a dict 
dct =   {'group1' : {'1': [0, 0], '2': [2, 2], '3': [3, 3], '4': [4, 4], '5': [5, 5]},
         'group2' : {'1': [2, 2], '2': [0, 0], '3': [4, 4], '4': [5, 5], '5': [6, 6]},
         'group3' : {'1': [3, 3], '2': [4, 4], '3': [0, 0], '4': [6, 6], '5': [7, 7]}}

example = ['2', '5', '3', '3', '1', '2']

for x in dct.keys():

    # As the first element of example should be the order(index + 1) of dct
    if example[0] in x:

        # declare the reference dict if the condition fulfilled  
        ref_dct = dct[x]
        break

# values of ref_dct if keys being elements of example. Create as list
ls = [ref_dct[x] for x in example]

print(ls) # Output : [[0, 0], [6, 6], [4, 4], [4, 4], [2, 2], [0, 0]]

